# eclipse refactoring - pull up method to interface

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

How can I change the default behaviour of eclipse so that it does not prepend the methods it pulls up to an interface with "public abstract"

example, I have a 
`class A` 
that implements 
`interface IA`. Suppose I added a method `void a()` to A, and I right click on that method, and select "Refactor->Pull Up", and than make sure `void a ()` is selected and I choose the `interface IA`, and click ok, a method called `public abstract void a();` gets created in IA, I want to get rid of the `public abstract` bit.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank You

Answer (score 10):

I was just looking at the same thing to see if it had changed and I found your question. In fact this is [Eclipse Bug 71627](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=71627). However there is a simple work around: instead of using *Refactor->Pull Up*, use *Quick fix (Ctrl+1)->Create 'method()' in super interface X*.

It also has the advantage that it leads you directly to the new method declaration, so that you can directly write the javadoc, change parameter names etc.

Comment: Nice workaround! Is there a possibility to do that for multiple methods?

Comment: This is the purpose of the _Refactor->Pull Up_. I guess if you have several methods to refactor then it is easier to use that one and then remove the `public abstract` than my workaround.

Comment: Yep pull up is the one, i too see the annoying "abstract" thing added. cool work around.

Comment: Notice that bug 71627 mentioned in my answer is about to be fixed (after 10 years!), however it won't get into Luna…