# Eclipse generating useless 'public abstract' modifier in interface method signatures

Tags: java, eclipse

While pulling up a method using the Eclipse refactoring tool, is there a way to impede generating the useless `public abstract` modifier in method signature of an interface?

Comment: Methods in Interfaces are by default public and abstract. No need to explicitly mention it.

Comment: @AniketThakur That's what he's trying to avoid.

Comment: Ohh Is Eclipse generating the modifiers for you?

Comment: Can you write more about how are you creating an interface and what are you writing methods. I never get this issue.

Comment: NetBeans IDE doesn't generate 'public abstract' when pulling up a method.

Comment: I've found similar question with workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537340/eclipse-refactoring-pull-up-method-to-interface

Comment: This post only concerns Eclipse user. You can ask Eclipse to pull up a method from a class that implements an interface. When you do so, Eclipse duplicates the signature of the method at the interface level, including the public abstract modifier, which is useless in the context of an interface.

Comment: The bug has been reported since 2004-08-09 and its status is always 'ASSIGNED' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Alexey. It sounds like an Eclipse bug, but it has a workaround. The bug has been reported since 2004-08-09 and its status is always 'ASSIGNED' :( –

Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537340/eclipse-refactoring-pull-up-method-to-interface)