# It is possible to get a warning if a interface method has redundant modifiers in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings

As you probably know, methods in interfaces are by default public abstract.

The JLS7 says: "It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the public and/or abstract modifier for a method declared in an interface."

Is there any option in Eclipse to generate warnings if **existing** interface methods have redundant modifiers? I didn't find any option in Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors / Warnings

Intellij IDEA has a similar feature, turned on by default.

I found some similar questions but they deal with code generation:

[Eclipse generating useless 'public abstract' modifier in interface method signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335939/eclipse-generating-useless-public-abstract-modifier-in-interface-method-signat)

[eclipse refactoring - pull up method to interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537340/eclipse-refactoring-pull-up-method-to-interface)

Eclipse fixed bug:

[[code style] don't generate redundant modifiers](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=71627)

Regards.

Comment: use 3rd party static code analyser like sonarqube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ comment, I found out that there is an Eclipse plug-in, called [SonarLint](http://www.sonarlint.org/eclipse/), that can connect to a SonarQube instance and mark detected problems in Java editor.